# JQuery Cycle Disable Next and Prev on slide

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I am working on a slideshow using jquery cycle. One thing I notice is during slide, the user can click and skip to the next slide before it finishes animating. Does anyone know the best method of disabling "next" and "previous" buttons while the animation is occuring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the docs it looks like you could do something using the `prevNextClick` and `after` events (disable after `prevNextClick` and enable after `after`.  The `after` event seems to be undocumented, but it appears in this demo: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/after.html

But if you can provide more information why you want to disable prev/next, someone might be able to give you a better solution.